# getting an error on ubuntu : Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to install JAVA . But Getting following error .

```
:~$ sudo apt-get update
Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
sudo: command not found
```

I dont know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can check content of PATH variable by executing command
$ echo $PATH

If you do not find /usr/bin in the output than you can append /usr/bin in PATH variable by executing command

$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin